# Serverless offline reload not working version 12

Tags: serverless, serverless-offline

Found some solutions where it was mentioned that by adding --reloadHandler it should work however i am getting below message when tried the command :
`serverless offline start --reloadHandler`

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Initializing provider configuration...
Environment: darwin, node 16.19.0, framework 3.26.0 (local) 3.7.3v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Detected unrecognized CLI options: "--reloadHandler".
```

Answer (score -1):

Had you installed 'serverless-offline' package ?

If so, on my side, I use package.json wih this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "serverless offline --reloadHandler"
}
```

The command `npm run start` works like a charm

Here are my serverless version:

```
"serverless": "3.38.0",
"serverless-offline": "13.3.2"
```